# Does Apple allow Paypal iphone sdk integration now?

Tags: iphone, ipad, paypal, payment-processing

In one of our project we have requirement of **payment processing**. We had few options along with the **Paypal**. But regarding Paypal integration of iPhone SDK does **APPLE** allow payment processing within the application ?

Application intend to sale tangible/intangible products for example it can be coupon or any service like hair trimming. In this case can we use Paypal integration ?

We had hard time to find out the same, so any one know about it please let us know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple allow using browser

checkout this link
https://www.x.com/community/ppx/xspaces/mobile

and see

Mobile Express Checkout Library (MECL): If you want the PayPal checkout flow to be in a browser or webview, you can use our Mobile Express Checkout Library. This is useful if you already have a express checkout integration completed for your website or **if app store policies require you to complete your checkout flow in a browser**. This library will help you integrate the mobile web flow into your app.

Comment: @Rams if want to use without browser ? and let say I used with browser than my application will quit. In that case How I would know that what is the status of the transaction ?

Comment: @ Jennis using Uiwebview paypal delegates will return status.

Comment: @Rams have you practically used paypal ? I mean you are sure of this so I will convey further to our management that we can proceed with paypal. Plz bear with my silly questions.

Comment: @jennis I have a source code But there is no file upload option in stack overflow

Comment: @Rams I downloaded the code from this link https://github.com/jenslukas/MB-iPhone-App/tree/bbe10d025afab49fa87fb1471634a7e923cf81eb#readme is it correct ? I am getting errors on building the project.

Comment: @Rams In this they have used MPL not MECL. If you find out any sample code related to that please mail me. BTW tons of thanks for link. That helped to clear my doubts.